# Object has no attribute even though function is defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

The error message that I get is:

```
'Network' object has no attribute '_block'
```

This is part of the code that I use:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels_img, features_d, num_classes, img_size):
        super(Network, self).__init__()

        self.critic = nn.Sequential(
            self._block(
                in_channels = features_d,
                out_channels = features_d * 2,
                kernel_size = (4, 4),
            )
        )

        def _block(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding):
            return nn.Conv2d(
                    in_channels = in_channels,
                    out_channels = out_channels,
                    kernel_size = kernel_size,
            )

        def forward(self, x, labels):
            return self.critic(x)

channels_img = 1
features_d = 16

model = Network(
        channels_img = channels_img,
        features_d = features_d,
        num_classes = 10,
        img_size = 28
).to(device)
```

(Please note that this is only a **minimal working example**, and that there is much more code. However, this code already leads to the described error message..)

Comment: The function _block is out of the scope of the Network class, check the indentations carefully.

Comment: Sorry, just checked, had it in correct in the code, but not in my answer, will edit now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. The code as shown has issues (namely, missing ``self``) but these would not lead to the described problem.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I was really careless, will provide a MWE asap.

Comment: Alright, please take a look at the minimal reproducible example, just checked that it really *is* reproducible.

Comment: Could my question please be reopened? I added a reproducible example, and I think it should be clear now what I had meant...

Comment: Both ``_block`` and ``forward`` are indented one level too deep – they are functions local to ``__init__``, not to the class as required for methods. Is that the actual indentation of your code?

Comment: Yup, good point ...

Comment: Could my question please be opened again? Why is it still closed!?

Comment: Your question is currently being reviewed for reopening; this will take some time, since there aren't many volunteers compared to the number of questions that need review. Note that even if the question is re-opened, it is likely to be closed again as a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing `self` parameters in the function.

Try like this:

```
def _block(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size): 
        [...]
```

Explanation:

> The self parameter is a reference to the current instance of the
> class, and is used to access variables that belongs to the class.
>
> It does not have to be named self , you can call it whatever you like,
> but it has to be the first parameter of any function in the class.

**Edit:**

As MisterMiyagi pointed out, although the missing `self` is a problem in itself, it would cause a different error, something like:

```
TypeError: _foo() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

**Edit #2**

Since the original question was posted, the question was update.

With this code there is an indentation issue.

The `_block` method is inside the `__init__` method (look at the indentation):

```
class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels_img, features_d, num_classes, img_size):
        super(Network, self).__init__()

        self.critic = nn.Sequential(
            self._block(
                in_channels = features_d,
                out_channels = features_d * 2,
                kernel_size = (4, 4),
            )
        )

        def _block(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding):
            ...
```

With fixed indentation the code works:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels_img, features_d, num_classes, img_size):
        super(Network, self).__init__()

        self.critic = nn.Sequential(
            self._block(
                in_channels = features_d,
                out_channels = features_d * 2,
                kernel_size = (4, 4),
                stride=None,
                padding=None,
            )
        )

    def _block(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding):
        return nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels = in_channels,
                out_channels = out_channels,
                kernel_size = kernel_size,
        )

    def forward(self, x, labels):
        return self.critic(x)

channels_img = 1
features_d = 16

model = Network(
        channels_img = channels_img,
        features_d = features_d,
        num_classes = 10,
        img_size = 28
).to(device)
print('Code ran!')
```

Output:

```
$ python3 test_so.py
Code ran!
```

There is another problem with the code your updated:

- `_block` is expecting two adicional arguments that you did not add in the method call in `__init__`, which gives this error: `TypeError: _block() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'stride' and 'padding'`. I added those arguments to make the example work;
- I added a print statement in the end to show that the code ran;

In summary, be careful with your indentation.

Comment: While missing ``self`` is a problem, it would lead to a different error. The error in the question shows that the *lookup* of ``_block`` fails, but a missing ``self`` would only lead to an error when calling the method after already looking it up.

Comment: You are right, this is true. The missing `self` would lead to a different error. Something like `TypeError: _foo() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`.

Comment: @David I edited my question. :)

Comment: @HulioAlmedo, updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're not passing the "self" parameter to the function, hence it doesn't recognize it as a method.

You should do `def _block(self, ...args):`

Comment: ``self`` is not required to be "recognized" as a method. The code as currently shown *does* define a method, it merely takes one less parameter than expected. This does not affect whether the method is visible or not, only whether it can take all the expected arguments.

Comment: I edited my question, please refer above.